# Create an 8 inch tablet emulator android for eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I am working in an android application that should support 7,8 and 10 inch tablets. I was able to create both 7 and 10 inch tablets emulator but not for 8 inch . Any one suggest me a solution to create an 8 inch tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse:

```
Windows -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions -> New
```

Configure the `screen size`.

Answer (score 2):

Open your android Device Manager-->>Device Definitions -->> New Device

```
Then fill up all function according to your 8.0" device information.

Then come back  to "Android Virtual Devices and Create new by newly create device"
```

Thanks